# Flutter: How to specify exact character to appear during email validation

Tags: regex, flutter, dart, email-verification

In my email validation, I want to make it mandatory that the user should use the full `.com` extension in there email field. Currently, the way I have my **RegExp** it only accepts starting with `.c` or `.o` or `.m` instead of throwing an error if there in no exact match with `.com`

How do I go about resolving this?

Here is my RegExp

```
final RegExp emailValidatorRegExp = RegExp(r"^[a-zA-Z0-9.]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+.com");
```

Comment: And then we will struggle for hours trying to fill out some web form, because someone thinks that email can be only in second-level domain in `.com` zone, and without hyphens or underscores before `@`.

Comment: @AlexanderMashin i know about adding hyphens or underscores but i don't need it for what i want to achieve. There is a reason i want it to appear that way. Don't try to think for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can check domains like `anything@string.com` and `anything@string.co.in`

```
void main() {
  var email = "jitsm555@gmail.com";
  bool emailValid = RegExp(r'^.+@[a-zA-Z]+\.{1}[a-zA-Z]+(\.{0,1}[a-zA-Z]+)$').hasMatch(email);
  print (emailValid); // true
}
```

Comment: jitsm555@@gmail.com
Not working returning valid email id